# Multiple activities inside dynamic content in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dynamic-content

I have the following pipeline in ADF:

[image: ]](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)

I have two activities pointing to a Failure SP which has the following parameters:
[image: Parameters]

It's currently set to print out an Error message if the Databricks Notebook fails, but I would like for it to also print an Error message if the Synapse_SP activity fails after the Notebook activity succeeds. Is it possible to add dynamic content to choose the error message from the activity that fails?

The current dynamic content is **@activity('Notebook').Error.message**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ADF, the activity flow will be like an **AND** operator. Here, your `Failure` SP activity will only be executed when both `Notebook` and `Synapse_SP` activities fails which won't happen as your flow is a sequential flow.

If your `Notebook` activity fails, then the flow won't execute the `Synapse_SP` activity because **it is after the success** of `Notebook` activity. That means `Failure` activity also won't execute as it is an **AND(both activity failure)**. So, your pipeline flow will be stopped at `Notebook` activity failure itself.

To achieve your requirement, you can follow two approaches.

**One** is you need to use **On Complete** and **On skipped** outcomes of the activities to obtain the **OR** of the activity outcomes.

Go through this [blog](https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/08/19/error-logging-and-the-art-of-avoiding-redundant-activities-in-azure-data-factory/) by **@Nandan Hegde** to understand about this approach.

**Another approach would be using two pipelines with Execute pipeline activity.** One is a master and other is a child.

Build your master pipeline like this.

[image]

Give your lookup activity in the parent pipeline- and use **Execute pipeline activity** to call the child pipeline. Give the activities which you want to check the errors in the child pipeline.

[image]

Here, instead of Notebook and SP activities, I have used two set variable activities with errors.

In the Execute pipeline activity, check the **Wait  on completion** checkbox.

[image]

Here, **we are handling the errors of all activities in the child pipeline by a single Execute pipeline activity in the parent pipeline**. If this child pipeline activity had any error, it stops the flow and **Execute pipeline activity also gives the same error**.

[image]

So, **get that failed activity name** and **error message** by using the below expressions.

Take a string type set variable activity **on the failure of the Execute pipeline** and use below expression to get the failed activity name.

```
@substring(activity('Execute Pipeline1').error.message,  add(indexOf(activity('Execute Pipeline1').error.message,'target'),7),  sub(indexOf(activity('Execute Pipeline1').error.message,'failed'),add(indexOf(activity('Execute Pipeline1').error.message,'target'),8)))
```

[image]

To get the error message use below expression.

```
@split(activity('Execute Pipeline1').error.message,'failed: ')[1]
```

[image]

These variables will give the outputs like below:

[image]

[image]

Use your `Failed` Stored procedure activity after these and pass the above variables as per your requirement.

**You can give your `Success` Stored procedure activity on the success of the Execute pipeline activity** and continue your logic from there.